# Match and Count Sequence Data

Tags: scala, match, sequence

I'm trying to match and count the data in the sequence data.What I have done so far as below:

```
val fruits = Seq("apple", "PEAR", "Pear")
fruits.exists(_.equalsIgnoreCase("pear"))
```

from here, how do we count the output as 2?

Comment: Use `count` instead of `exists` - As I always say, the **Scaladoc** is your friend: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html

Answer (score 1):

`exists` returns the boolean value so it will tell whether particular keyword exists or not in collection.

To find the count,

```
fruits.count(_.equalsIgnoreCase("pear"))
```